# Expand last grid row to fill window in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following Grid setup in a WPF application.

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="220" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="180*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <!-- some content -->
 </Grid>
```

What I want is for the final row to take up as much height as available in its parent. But it  does not seem to honor my '*' command in the final row definition.

Please note that I want all other row heights to be fixed..

Is this possible? If so how? Any help or pointers are appreciated..

Comment: what is the content in the last row, make sure you have removed `VerticalAlignment` and `Height` property settings from there.

Comment: Also, it will work but you don't actually need to use `180*` as this is the only remaining row. And you are telling the Grid to evenly divide the space left into 180 parts, and the last row will take all of them (180). it only became meaningful if you have multiple rows and you want them to not evenly take the remaining space (eg. `1*` (or just `*`) and `2*` means divide into 3 parts, one take 1 of it, the other will take 2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

place height="*" in last row.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="220" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have written should be fine (though as @Bolu commented, the `180*` could be replaced with `*` in this case).  If the content in the last row is not expanding to fill the available size, I would suspect one of the following:

1. The `Grid` may be nested somewhere below a layout panel that does not arrange its children to fill all available vertical space.  For example, is one of the `Grid` panel's ancestors a `StackPanel`?  A good way to test whether this is the culprit is to comment out the entire `Grid` and replace it with a `Border` with an easily distinguishable background (e.g., `Magenta`) and see if it occupies the entire area you expect the `Grid` to fill.
2. There may not actually be any content in the last row.  Did you set the correct `Grid.Row` value correctly?
3. You may be overriding the layout behavior of the last row's content.  Are you setting the content's `VerticalAlignment` to anything other than `Stretch`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Height` property from the last Row:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="220" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!-- some content -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: For completeness, Height="*" also works and has a slightly different meaning.